# Logon failed error message is thrown while verifying database

Tags: c#, windows, crystal-reports

In dbcon:

```
Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=fdbr;User ID=sa;Pwd=pass123;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Integrated Security=false;
```

Error is thrown on this line of code:

```
objLib.SetReportConnection(objcr);
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct credentials of the user? is the user authorized to access the database fdbr? You need to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

connection string probably like this if you use local server

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=fdbr;user id=sa;password=pass123;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Integrated Security=true;
```

this link may help you https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/